# How can I have more than one join with the same table

Tags: mysql, scala, anorm

In Scala anorm with MySQL, it seems joining more than once the same table in a query and working with aliases only returns the value of the last table included in the query.

It seems the last join automatically overrides all the previous values even though it has a different alias.

See example below.

Say I have a table `mytable`

```
id | name
1  | name1
2  | name2
```

And in `mymaintable` a record: `myId1 = 1` and `myId2 = 2`

If I do

```
SELECT
t1.*, t2.*
FROM mymaintable AS m
JOIN mytable AS t1 ON t1.id = m.myId1
JOIN mytable AS t2 ON t2.id = m.myId2
```

I would expect `1, name1, 2, name2`

Now in Anorm i would define aliaser so that

```
val aliaser = new ColumnAliaser {
      def as1 = ColumnAliaser.withPattern((0 to 2).toSet, "t1.")
      def as2 = ColumnAliaser.withPattern((2 to 4).toSet, "t2.")

      def apply(column: (Int, ColumnName)): Option[String] = as1(column).orElse(as2(column))
    }
```

and the result would be `2, name2, 2, name2`

Is this a bug? Am I doing anything wrong?

It might be worth noting that I use anorm 2.5.3

Comment: You don't really explain what's the issue, with details

Comment: I added one sentence, hopefully makes it clearer. I also added the anorm version.

Comment: it doesn't, if there is an error, paste the error trace/details